# Firebase Messages in Swift not showing up when application isn't active

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement firebase messaging into my application but I am only receiving the notifications when the application is active (I can see them in the console, but only when the app is in the active state. If it is closed they don't appear until the app is active again).

I have background notifications turned on, as well as my p12 certificate loaded into the firebase settings.

Here is the code in my app delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    FirebaseApp.configure()


    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
        print("IOS 11")
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    }else if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    return true
}

 func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}

@nonobjc func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    // Convert to pretty-print JSON
    guard let data =
        try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: remoteMessage.appData, options: .prettyPrinted),
        let prettyPrinted = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return
    }
    print("Received direct channel message:\n\(prettyPrinted)")
}

func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage){

    print("Received Remote Message")
    guard let data =
        try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: remoteMessage.appData, options: .prettyPrinted),
        let prettyPrinted = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return
    }
    print("Received direct channel message:\n\(prettyPrinted)")

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
}
```

Edit 1:
and here is a sample notification I receive in the console

```
{
  "from" : "480981200252",
  "notification" : {
    "e" : "1",
    "body" : "hey"
  },
  "collapse_key" : "com.amplesftwr.thelifeofcarl"
}
```

Edit 2:
Here is a photo of my background modes settings:
[image: background modes]

Comment: just to be sure, this works on iOS 10, but not 11?

Comment: I am not sure If it works on 10, I am using 11.

Comment: Update: same result on ios 10

Comment: can you take a screenshot of your background modes enabled? You app receives correctly in the foreground, so you must not be setting something correct in the settings related to it being in the background.

Comment: Also check to see if you "Allowed" Notifications for your app/device

Comment: notifications are turned on for the app. I have uploaded a photo of the background modes to the original post above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Project Settings, under Capabilities, make sure that not only "Push Notifications" is turned on, but also "Background Modes".

In your .plist file you should also have a key "Required background modes", and in your project make sure you have the .entitlements file as well.

An other thing you might want to check is, when you go to the Firebase Console, instead of sending the notification to only the token of this specific user, try sending the message to all the users of the app using this option in the Firebase Console.

If it works then, your problem might have something to do with the FCM Token.

If it still doesn't work then you might want to check that in your Key Chain and all your certificates on your Apple Developer Account to make sure everything is all green/okay and that there is no duplicates !

I could not comment your post unfortunately so I added it here as an answer, hopefully it will help you solving your problem but if it doesn't, well, just let me know and I will try my best :)

Comment: Alex, thanks for all of the suggestions. Push notifications is turned on. The plist has required background modes and I am already doing a push to the entire app, not a single user. Sadly I have tried all of those things before posting :/

Comment: Update: I even tried revoking the certificate, and re-adding it (to firebase as well) and still the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the update Benjamin! I will get back to you tomorrow morning, maybe things will be clearer after a good sleep :)

Comment: By the way, are you sending the notifications to a real device or the simulator ?

Comment: Still no luck, even after a good night of sleep. This is to a real device. I have tried several devices at this point

Comment: your image looks right, the only other thing I would check the entitlement. You would have to see something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Pgo.png) image(just as Alex said). Beyond that Idk. Sorry. @BenjaminPorter

Comment: I checked the entitlement and it checked out fine. Decided to try out AWS SNS and I had it working within a couple of minutes.